# How can I receive notifications of filesystem changes in OS X?

Tags: macos, events, filesystems, hfs+

In Windows, I can use the FindNextChangeNotification API to watch a file or folder for changes. For example, I can watch a folder and get notified when a file is added or removed.

Is there a similar API on OS X?

Comment: It occurs to me that I could do this with Spotlight, but I'm looking for a more low-level solution.

Comment: also check out [fswatch from this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515730/is-there-a-command-like-watch-or-inotifywait-on-the-mac/13807906#13807906)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Mac OS X v10.5 introduces the File System Events API. Have a look at:

- [File System Events API Collection](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/file_system_events)
- [Technology Overview](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/TechnologyOverview/TechnologyOverview.html) (archive)
- [Using the File System Events API](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/UsingtheFSEventsFramework/UsingtheFSEventsFramework.html) (archive)
- [File System Events Programming Guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20110805060426/http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/FSEvents_ProgGuide.pdf) (PDF of 2008)

Comment: Thou rockest, Monsieur Thivent. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

[FSEvents](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FSEvents) is nice, but for watching just a small set of files or folders it's rather overkill, and it does require Leopard or newer.  (The underlying technology was introduced in Tiger, but the API wasn't public.)

As a possible alternative, note that OS X inherits [kqueue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kqueue) from FreeBSD (at least as of Panther).  You can search for examples of `EVFILT_VNODE` usage, that's what you want to use to watch for file alterations.