# Is there a command like "watch" or "inotifywait" on the Mac?

Tags: macos, watch, inotify

I want to watch a folder on my Mac and then execute a bash script, passing it the name of whatever file/folder was just moved into or created in the watched directory.

Comment: You should ask how DropBox does it since presumably they tried all the available options.

Comment: @JeffBurdges I'm not so sure that'd be an easy undertaking. However I would say after skimming over Apple's [FSEvents Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/FSEvents_Ref/Reference/reference.html) it would be really silly if Dropbox wasn't making use of this. The `fswatch` util presented as an answer below does in fact use this method.

Comment: @JeffBurdges: it's not funny.

Answer (score 537, accepted):

## fswatch

[`fswatch`](https://github.com/alandipert/fswatch) is a small program using the Mac OS X FSEvents API to monitor a directory.
When an event about any change to that directory is received, the specified
shell command is executed by `/bin/bash`

If you're on GNU/Linux,
[`inotifywatch`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywatch) (part of the
`inotify-tools` package on most distributions) provides similar
functionality.

**Update:** `fswatch` can now be used across many platforms including BSD, Debian, and Windows.

### Syntax / A Simple Example

The new way that can watch multiple paths - for **versions 1.x and higher**:

```
fswatch -o ~/path/to/watch | xargs -n1 -I{} ~/script/to/run/when/files/change.sh
```

> Note: The number output by `-o` will get added to the end of the `xargs` command if not for the `-I{}`. If you do choose to use that number, place `{}` anywhere in your command.

The older way for **versions 0.x**:

```
fswatch ~/path/to/watch ~/script/to/run/when/files/change.sh
```

### Installation with Homebrew

As of 9/12/13 it was added back in to [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) - yay! So, update your formula list (`brew update`) and then all you need to do is:

```
brew install fswatch
```

### Installation without Homebrew

Type these commands in `Terminal.app`

```
cd /tmp
git clone https://github.com/alandipert/fswatch
cd fswatch/
make
cp fswatch /usr/local/bin/fswatch
```

If you don't have a `c` compiler on your system you may need to install Xcode or Xcode command line tools - both free. However, if that is the case, you should probably just [check out homebrew](http://brew.sh/).

### Additional Options for `fswatch` version 1.x

```
Usage:
fswatch [OPTION] ... path ...

Options:
 -0, --print0          Use the ASCII NUL character (0) as line separator.
 -1, --one-event       Exit fsw after the first set of events is received.
 -e, --exclude=REGEX   Exclude paths matching REGEX.
 -E, --extended        Use exended regular expressions.
 -f, --format-time     Print the event time using the specified format.
 -h, --help            Show this message.
 -i, --insensitive     Use case insensitive regular expressions.
 -k, --kqueue          Use the kqueue monitor.
 -l, --latency=DOUBLE  Set the latency.
 -L, --follow-links    Follow symbolic links.
 -n, --numeric         Print a numeric event mask.
 -o, --one-per-batch   Print a single message with the number of change events.
                       in the current batch.
 -p, --poll            Use the poll monitor.
 -r, --recursive       Recurse subdirectories.
 -t, --timestamp       Print the event timestamp.
 -u, --utc-time        Print the event time as UTC time.
 -v, --verbose         Print verbose output.
 -x, --event-flags     Print the event flags.

See the man page for more information.
```

Comment: Your instructions or installing without homebrew don't seem to work any more. `make` throws an error about not finding a makefile. Fortunately, fswatch is now on MacPorts, so `sudo port install fswatch` works, for those of us using MacPorts instead of Homebrew.

Comment: If you are using a command with static arguments (for example, I was running my unit tests on src and test changes) this might not work for you. This question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25689589/how-to-run-fswatch-to-call-a-program-with-static-arguments) was the the second piece I needed.

Comment: I hear you out there: `fswatch ./ | xargs -I{} cp {} ~/Dropbox/backup/latest/`

Comment: fswatch is better than tools like entr or when_changed, which have some bugs when dealing with .git directory. fswatch is much more professional. Simply, you just `fswatch .` will monitor current directory.

Comment: I would suggest `fswatch -0 -v -o /path/to/watched/files | xargs -0 -n 1 -I {} [your command]` with `-0` for NULLs. This one works for me for less compilation

Comment: Thanks for this. This answer has a lot of historical information that could be deleted, maybe? I'm just trying to watch a file and I need to do this `while true; do fswatch --one-event eraseme-001.swift && swift eraseme-001.swift; done`... is there a way to do it without the `while`?

Comment: @DanRosenstark You are having to use `while` because you are choosing to use `--one-event`. The equivalent is `fswatch eraseme-001.swift | xargs -n1 -I{} swift {}`

Comment: can fswatch watch for additions / deletions of files?

Answer (score 108):

You can use [launchd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) for that purpose. Launchd can be configured to automatically launch a program when a file path is modified.

For example the following launchd config plist will launch the program `/usr/bin/logger` when the desktop folder of my user account is modified:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>logger</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/bin/logger</string>
        <string>path modified</string>
    </array>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/sakra/Desktop/</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

To activate the config plist save it to the LaunchAgents folder in your Library folder as "logger.plist".

From the shell you can then use the command `launchctl` to activate the logger.plist by running:

$ launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/logger.plist

The desktop folder is now being monitored. Every time it is changed you should see an output in the system.log (use Console.app).
To deactivate the logger.plist, run:

```
$ launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/logger.plist
```

The configuration file above uses the `WatchPaths` option. Alternatively you can also use the
`QueueDirectories` option. See the [launchd](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/8/launchd/) man page for more information.

Comment: is there a way to have it monitor change in file content as well as the file path?

Comment: I don't think so. You can use [opensnoop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/opensnoop.1m.html) for that purpose.

Comment: I got this to work, but then when I switched `/usr/bin/logger` with my Bash script and removed the `"<string>path modified</strong>"` entry, I couldn't find any way for my bash script to know which file on my desktop was modified -- just that the event occurred. I tried looking at `$0`, `$1` and only got the script name itself, noting passed to it.

Comment: Also, does this thing go into a loop once it detects a change, rather than only launching (and stopping) when it detects a change? I'd rather it work on demand, not keep running in a loop telling me that, for instance, 2 days ago, something changed on my desktop, writing that in the log over and over again. So, do we need to use some kind of interval option in this plist?

Comment: @Volomike If by "thing" you mean `launchd`, it's a system daemon and is always running. If by "thing" you mean the program in the plist, [launchd runs the command in response to each watch event](https://manpagez.com/man/5/launchd.plist/); it's up to your program/script to terminate itself instead of loop.

Answer (score 50):

Facebook's [watchman](https://github.com/facebook/watchman), available via Homebrew, also looks nice. It supports also filtering:

> These two lines establish a watch on a source directory and then set
>   up a trigger named "buildme" that will run a tool named "minify-css"
>   whenever a CSS file is changed. The tool will be passed a list of the
>   changed filenames.
>
> `$ watchman watch ~/src`
>
> `$ watchman -- trigger ~/src buildme '*.css' -- minify-css`

Notice that the path must be absolute.

Comment: This is by far the best tool.

Comment: This is a very nice little program: The docs are great, it doesn't open an infinite loop (which is what fswatch seems to do) and it remembers the watches you've created after reboot and auto starts them up again.

Comment: @BentOnCoding Could you elaborate how you came to that conclusion?

Comment: I did a large amount of research comparing various solutions. The functionality is very robust, and works consistently.

Answer (score 24):

You might want to take a look at (and maybe expand) my little tool [`kqwait`](https://github.com/sschober/kqwait). Currently it just sits around and waits for a write event on a single file, but the [kqueue](http://people.freebsd.org/~jlemon/papers/kqueue.pdf) architecture allows for hierarchical event stacking...

Comment: Works so far on mountain lion. Very nice!

Comment: So this is actually really awesome. I ran into a little issue with `fswatch` (which is fine too, since its such a light wrapper it could also be modified to do the proper thing I'm sure) where it would fire when running things like `git status` (which is actually run every time zsh prompt is rendered on my machine...) which actually kinda screws up this elaborate script i have by creating an endless feedback loop. kqwait, however, provides the info about the changed file, and is not tripped by `git status`. I do need it to fire on write though.

Comment: `$ brew install kqwait && while true; do kqwait doc/my_file.md; make; done`

Comment: Simple, works like a charm on Mojave (and probably on any future Mac OS).

Answer (score 17):

[watchdog](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog) is a cross-platform python API for watching files / directories, and it has builtin "tricks" tool that allows you to trigger actions (including shell commands) when events occur (including new added file, removed file and changed file).

Answer (score 15):

This is just to mention [entr](http://eradman.com/entrproject/) as an alternative on OSX to run arbitrary commands when files change. I find it simple and useful.

- `brew install entr` on macos
- `apt install entr` on Debian/Ubuntu

Answer (score 6):

Here's a one-liner using [`sschober`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/321307/sschober)'s [tool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8995427/1081801).

```
$ while true; do kqwait ./file-to-watch.js; script-to-execute.sh; done
```

Comment: `$ brew install kqwait`

Answer (score 4):

Apple OSX [Folder Actions](http://www.simplehelp.net/2007/01/30/folder-actions-for-os-x-explained-with-real-world-examples/) allow you to automate tasks based on actions taken on a folder.

Comment: Yeah I know, i'v tried to use that several times, never successfully gotten it to work, could you give me an example?

Comment: That's a link, not an answer

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:** `fsw` has been merged into [`fswatch`](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch).  In this answer, any reference to `fsw` should now read `fswatch`.

I wrote an `fswatch` replacement in C++ called `fsw` which features several improvements:

- It's a GNU Build System project which builds on any supported platform (OS X v. >= 10.6) with

  ```
  ./configure && make && sudo make install
  ```
- Multiple paths can be passed as different arguments:

  ```
  fsw file-0 ... file-n
  ```
- It dumps a detailed record with all the event information such as:

  ```
  Sat Feb 15 00:53:45 2014 - /path/to/file:inodeMetaMod modified isFile
  ```
- Its output is easy to parse so that `fsw` output can be piped to another process.
- Latency can be customised with `-l, --latency`.
- Numeric event flags can be written instead of textual ones with `-n, --numeric`.
- The time format can be customised using `strftime` format strings with `-t, --time-format`.
- The time can be the *local* time of the machine (by default) or UTC time with `-u, --utc-time`.

Getting fsw:

`fsw` is [hosted on GitHub](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fsw) and can be obtained cloning its repository:

```
    git clone https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fsw
```

Installing fsw:

`fsw` can be installed using the following commands:

```
    ./configure && make && sudo make install
```

Further information:

I also wrote an introductory [blog post](http://thegreyblog.blogspot.com/2014/02/fsw-file-system-event-notifier-for-mac.html) where you can find a couple of examples about how `fsw` works.

Answer (score 2):

My fork of [fswatch](https://github.com/unphased/fswatch) provides the functionality of `inotifywait -m` with slightly less (no wait, more! I have a lot more troubles on Linux with `inotifywait`...) parse-friendly output.

It is an improvement upon the original `fswatch` because it sends out the actual path of the changed file over STDOUT rather than requiring you to provide a program that it forks.

It's been rock solid as the foundation of a series of scary bash scripts I use to automate stuff.

(this is off-topic) `inotifywait` on Linux, on the other hand, requires a lot of kludges on top of it and I still haven't figured out a good way to manage it, though I think something based on `node.js` might be the ticket.

Comment: Right, fork of fswatch. Is _that_ on Homebrew?

Comment: The answer is no; but they're [working on it](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/13110).

To install it really quickly just 
`brew install https://raw.github.com/mlevin2/homebrew/116b43eaef08d89054c2f43579113b37b4a2abd3/Library/Formula/fswatch.rb`

Answer (score 2):

I have a GIST for this and the usage is pretty simple

```
watchfiles <cmd> <paths...>
```

To illustrate, the following command will echo `Hello World` every time that `file1` OR `file2` change; and the default interval check is 1 second

```
watchfiles 'echo Hello World' /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2
```

If I want to check every 5 seconds I can use the `-t` flag

```
watchfiles -t 'echo Hello World' /path/to/file1 /path/to/file2
```

- `-v` enables the `verbose` mode which shows debug information
- `-q` makes `watchfiles` execute quietly (`#` will be shown so the user can see the program is executing)
- `-qq` makes `watchfiles` execute completely quietly
- `-h` shows the help and usage

https://gist.github.com/thiagoh/5d8f53bfb64985b94e5bc8b3844dba55

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this for macOS. I'm sure this is terrible in many ways:

```
#!/bin/sh
# watchAndRun
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
    echo "Use like this:"
    echo "   $0 filename-to-watch command-to-run"
    exit 1
fi
if which fswatch >/dev/null; then
    echo "Watching $1 and will run $2"
    while true; do fswatch --one-event $1 >/dev/null && $2; done
else
    echo "You might need to run: brew install fswatch"
fi
```

Comment: I couldn't figure out fswatch syntax without the while. Which is annoying and makes the script hard to stop.

Answer (score 1):

sudo fs_usage -f filesys | grep "interesting thing" ?

Comment: Is this a question or an answer?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Thanks for posting the only option which runs directly on the terminal without installing third party software.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use NodeJS, you can use a package called [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) (or [chokidar-cli](https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/chokidar-cli) actually) for the watching and then use `rsync` (included with Mac):

Rsync command:

`$ rsync -avz --exclude 'some-file' --exclude 'some-dir' './' '/my/destination'`

Chokidar cli (installed globally via npm):

`chokidar \"**/*\" -c \"your-rsync-command-above\"`

Answer (score 0):

I can wholeheartedly recommend using [watchexec](https://watchexec.github.io/). Built in Rust and It Just Works™ no matter which platform you're on! Straightforward CLI options as well.

Answer (score -3):

Here's a simple single line alternative for users who don't have the `watch` command who want to execute a command every 3 seconds:

`while :; do your-command; sleep 3; done`

It's an infinite loop that is basically the same as doing the following:

`watch -n3 your-command`

Comment: This is NOT the same as using a library that listens for events from the filesystem. If in your example, `your-command` does disk I/O, then that's a *guaranteed* disk read/write every 3 seconds — or 10,800 times every *hour.* By using filesystem events you would be guaranteed that I/O (and other expensive operations) only happen when you change a file (which generally is only a couple of times an hour.)

Comment: True, and good to consider. I usually need to `watch` things for temporary amounts of time to see what something is doing. I don't use my mentioned technique for production apps or anything like that. For example, I'd like to see the progress of `dd`, and my technique makes it happen (replacing `your-command` as appropriate to send the appropriate signal to `dd`).