# Program to re-run, eg, `make` when files are modified?

Tags: makefile

Is there a program that will automatically re-run, eg, `make`, when files are modified?

For example, when I'm writing `sphinx` documentation, it would be nice if `make html` was run automatically each time I edit any relevant files.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For simple things, rerun could be a good fit: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/rerun

"Command-line executable Python script to re-run the given command every time files are modified in the current directory or its subdirectories."

It requires a Python interpreter, but does not care if your command or files are written in Python.

```
Usage

rerun [--help|-h] [--verbose|-v] [--ignore|-i=<file>] [--version] <command>
Where:

<command>           Command to execute
--help|-h           Show this help message and exit.
--ignore|-i=<file>  File or directory to ignore. Any directories of the
                    given name (and their subdirs) are excluded from the
                    search for changed files. Any modification to files of
                    the given name are ignored. The given value is
                    compared to basenames, so for example, "--ignore=def"
                    will skip the contents of directory "./abc/def/" and
                    will ignore file "./ghi/def". Can be specified multiple
                    times.
--verbose|-v        Display the names of changed files before the command
                    output.
--version           Show version number and exit.
```

Comment: Can be installed with apt on ubuntu systems: apt install rerun

Comment: According to [their own project description](https://pypi.org/project/rerun/): “In most circumstances, this project is superceded by [rerun2](https://github.com/tartley/rerun2) a ten-line Bash script”

Answer (score 6):

In Linux, you can use this command line:

```
while true; do inotifywait -e close_write  *.py; make; done
```

Uses standard system command `inotifywait`, if not available, install with something like:

```
sudo apt install inotify-tools
```

Comment: Because the question isn't tagged with linux, and might even be running on Windows, it it would help if you mention what OS this solution is for.

Comment: It is true. Thanks. I did not realize I wasn't in askubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

Well, since make will not do anything if nothing has changed, how about

```
while true; do sleep 60; make html; done
```

or the equivalent in your shell of choice? I don't think the usual file system layers are event-driven in such a way that they will you notify you of file changes without doing some similar themselves, but it's possibly DBUS can do that sort of stuff.

Comment: D'oh. Of course. The only problem with that is that it would make errors harder to read (ie, because they would scroll up half way through reading them).

Comment: @David Wolever: "make html || sleep 900" should fix that.

Comment: Awe… But then I've got to wait 900 after I fix the error. And, hey! Are you saying it would take me 15 minutes to fix errors?! ;)

Comment: @David Wolever: been a while since I had misbehaving shell scripts... wouldn't the first Ctrl-C just interrupt the sleep and send you back into the loop? I know stubborn scripts take a good bashing (oh dear, what an awful pun) on the keys to interrupt.

Comment: hahah :D But, yes, a ^C would put me back into the loop… But then I'm switching back to the terminal, which is what I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Good incentive to make less errors. :D OK, I have nothing constructive to add at this point.

Comment: AFAIK, Make can do a lot of work even if nothing changed. You are assuming that the build succeeded. Is there a way to tell Make to do nothing if nothing changed, even if the previous build failed?

Answer (score 2):

You could use inotifywait in a loop: https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki/#info

Answer (score 2):

As per answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22907316/71522 `watchman` seems to work very well:

```
 $ watchman-make -p '*.c' 'Makefile' -t all
```

Will re-run `make all` each time any `*.c` or `Makefile` file changes.

It can be installed with:

```
$ brew install watchman
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use incron: http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en

Answer (score 0):

This question was also asked here: https://superuser.com/questions/181517/how-to-execute-a-command-whenever-a-file-changes/

You could try [reflex](https://github.com/cespare/reflex)

```
# Rerun make whenever a .c file changes
reflex -r '\.c$' make
```