# Track a file [C++ or Python]

Tags: c++, python, file, path, tracking

How can I "track" a file using C++, or Python (I'm guessing C++ will be way more powerfull. Just putting Python in there in case there is a way with it, which would be simpler than C++).

When I mean track, I mean registering any moving of the file to a different path, changes in name, etc. Changes in the actual content of the file isn't an issue.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515730/is-there-a-command-like-watch-or-inotifywait-on-the-mac

Comment: I disagree with the votes to close on duplicate - the question doesn't specify the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(migrated from comment)

You can do that using launchd on OS X. Check out: [Is there a command like "watch" or "inotifywait" on the Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515730/is-there-a-command-like-watch-or-inotifywait-on-the-mac)

Comment: Yup, was waiting for you to make it an answer to accept. Pity you can't accept comments.