# Is there a "watch" / "monitor" / "guard" program for Makefile dependencies?

Tags: c++, build, makefile, filesystems, guard

I've recently been spoiled by using [nodemon](https://npmjs.org/package/nodemon) in a terminal window, to run my Node.js program whenever I save a change.

I would like to do something similar with some C++ code I have. My actual project has lots of source files, but if we assume the following example, I would like to run `make` automatically whenever I save a change to `sample.dat`, `program.c` or `header.h`.

```
test: program sample.dat
    ./program < sample.dat

program: program.c header.h
    gcc program.c -o program
```

Is there an existing solution which does this?

(Without firing up an IDE. I know lots of IDEs can do a project rebuild when you change files.)

Comment: If you're on linux you can use a bash script and `inotifywait`.

Comment: Here's an alternative build system that has a pretty nice monitor mode: http://gittup.org/tup/ just do `tup monitor -a -f`

Comment: I think this question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515730/is-there-a-command-like-watch-or-inotifywait-on-the-mac, or, in the very least the fswatch answer also answers this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515730/is-there-a-command-like-watch-or-inotifywait-on-the-mac#answer-13807906

Answer (score 5):

If you are on a platform that supports [`inotifywait`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait) (to my knowledge, only Linux; but since you asked about Make, it seems there's a good chance you're on Linux; for OS X, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1515730/834176)), you can do something like this:

```
inotifywait --exclude '.*\.swp|.*\.o|.*~' --event MODIFY -q -m -r . |
while read
do make
done
```

Breaking that down:

```
inotifywait
```

Listen for file system events.

```
--exclude '.*\.swp|.*\.o|.*~'
```

Exclude files that end in `.swp`, `.o` or `~` (you'll probably want to add to this list).

```
--event MODIFY
```

When you find one print out the filepath of the file for which the event occurred.

```
-q
```

Do not print startup messages (so make is not prematurely invoked).

```
-m
```

Listen continuously.

```
-r .
```

Listen recursively on the current directory. Then it is piped into a simple loop which invokes make for every line read.

Tailor it to your needs. You may find `inotifywait --help` and the manpage helpful.

---

Here is a more detailed script. I haven't tested it much, so use with discernment. It is meant to keep the build from happening again and again needlessly, such as when switching branches in Git.

```
#!/bin/sh
datestampFormat="%Y%m%d%H%M%S"
lastrun=$(date +$datestampFormat)
inotifywait --exclude '.*\.swp|.*\.o|.*~' \
            --event MODIFY \
            --timefmt $datestampFormat \
            --format %T \
            -q -m -r . |
while read modified; do
    if [ $modified -gt $lastrun ]; then
        make
        lastrun=$(date +$datestampFormat)
    fi
done
```