# How to run fswatch to call a program with static arguments?

Tags: macos, bash, watch, fswatch

I used to use fswatch v0.0.2 like so (in this instance to run django test suit when a file changed)

`$>fswatch . 'python manage.py test'`

this works fine.

I wanted to exclude some files that were causing the test to run more than once per save (Sublime text was saving a .tmp file, and I suspect .pyc files were also causing this)

So I upgraded fswatch to enable the -e  mode.

However the way fswatch has changed which is causing me troubles - it now accepts a pipe argument like so:

`$>fswatch . | xargs -n1 program`

I can't figure out how to pass in arguments to the program here. e.g. this does not work:

`$>fswatch . | xargs -n1 python manage.py test`

nor does this:

`$>fswatch . | xargs -n1 'python manage.py test'`

how can I do this without packaging up my command in a bash script?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`fswatch` documentation (either the [Texinfo manual](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxZtP9CHH-Q6bHF3bmJGRmlVcVU&usp=sharing), or the [wiki](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch/wiki), or [`README`](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch)) have examples of how this is done:

```
$ fswatch [opts] -0 -o path ... | xargs -0 -n1 -I{} your full command goes here
```

Pitfalls:

- `xargs -0`, `fswatch -0`: use it to make sure paths with newlines are interpreted correctly.
- `fswatch -o`: use it to have `fswatch` "bubble" all the events in the set into a single one printing only the number of records in the set.
- `-I{}`: specifying a placeholder is the trick you missed for `xargs` interpreting correctly your command arguments in those cases where you *do* not want the record (in this case, since `-o` was used, the number of records in the set) to be passed down to the command being executed.

Comment: have marked this as correct as it answers the crux of my initial question - using xargs without passing the output as arguments to the command to be run.

Comment: I think the "-o" option should go with fswatch, not xargs.

Answer (score 28):

Alternative answer not fighting xargs' default reason for being - passing on the output as arguments to the command to be run.

`fswatch . | (while read; do python manage.py test; done)`

Which is still a bit wordy/syntaxy, so I have created a super simple bash script `fswatch-do` that simplifies things for me:

```
#!/bin/bash  
(while read; do "$@"; done)
```

usage:

`fswatch -r -o -e 'pyc' somepath | fswatch-do python manage.py test someapp.SomeAppTestCase`

Comment: If being run within a Bourne shell (as can happen in a subprocess invocation depending on one's config) the `read` command will need a dummy argument.

Comment: There is no need to wrap the last part of the pipeline in parantheses to make a subshell.

Answer (score 2):

Here's my little function that I use with fswatch for running a command on save, since the full fswatch was hard to remember:

```
function run_on_save () {
  fswatch -0 -o $1 |  xargs -0 -n1 -I{} ${@:2}
}
```

It passes the first argument (`$1`) to fswatch, and passes the remaining arguments (${@:2}) to xargs.

To use it, do `run_on_save <path to watch> <command to run>`.

**Examples**

1. Print "hello" each time `myfile.txt` is ran: `run_on_save myfile.txt echo "hello"`.
2. To run a python test every time you edit a file in a python project ([there are better ways to do exactly this though](https://github.com/olzhasar/pytest-watcher)):

```py
run_on_save project_folder pytest .
```

Improvements are welcome.