# Create a bash script that runs and updates a log whenever a file is deleted

Tags: bash, file, cron, delete-file

I am new to bash scripting and I have to create a script that will run on all computers within my group at work (so it's not just checking one computer). We have a spreadsheet that keeps certain file information, and I am working to automate the updating of that spreadsheet. I already have an existing python script that gathers the information needed and writes to the spreadsheet.

What I need is a bash script (cron job, maybe?) that is activated anytime a user deletes a file that matches a certain extension within the specified file path. The script should hold on to the file name before it is completely deleted. I don't need any other information besides the name.

Does anyone have any suggestions for where I should begin with this? I've searched a bit but not found anything useful yet.

It would be something like:

```
 for folders and files in path:
      if file ends in .txt and is being deleted:
            save file name
```

Comment: if you're on linux, then look into inotify, which can trigger actions based on events in the filesystem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To save the name of every file `.txt` deleted in some directory `path` or any of its subdirectories, run:

```
inotifywait -m -e delete --format "%w%f" -r "path" 2>stderr.log | grep '\.txt$' >>logfile
```

Explanation:

- `-m` tells inotifywait to keep running.  The default is to exit after the first event
- `-e delete` tells inotifywait to only report on file delete events.
- `--format "%w%f"` tells inotifywait to print only the name of the deleted file
- `path` is the target directory to watch.
- `-r` tells inotifywait to monitor subdirectories of `path` recursively.
- `2>stderr.log` tells the shell to save stderr output to a file named `stderr.log`.  As long as things are working properly, you may ignore this file.
- `>>logfile`  tells the shell to redirect all output to the file `logfile`.  If you leave this part off, output will be directed to stdout and you can watch in real time as files are deleted.
- `grep '\.txt$'` limits the output to files with `.txt` extensions.

#### Mac OSX

Similar programs are available for OSX.  See ["Is there a command like “watch” or “inotifywait” on the Mac?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515730/is-there-a-command-like-watch-or-inotifywait-on-the-mac).

Comment: thank you! also, the explanation is very very helpful! as a new bash scripter, those one-liners are difficult to figure out.

Comment: I'm trying to figure out these keywords that seem to be used as extensions in several one-liners on bash (such as -name, -type, etc). I don't know where to look for a list of these, or if they are solely dependent on the current command. Could you point me in the right direction? Thank you!!

Comment: @user3938558 The first place to look for those "extensions" (also called "options") is in the man page for that command.  From the command line, run `man inotifywait` and scroll down and you will see documentation for all the options that we used here.  (Also see `man grep` for the `grep` command.) If you saw a one-line that used the options `-name` and `-type`, my guess is that you were looking at a `find` command.  In that case, type `man find`.  Although some are written better than others, man-pages all have similar format.  Once you get used to the format, you will find them very helpful.

Comment: okay thank you. i'll look at those. I'm finding it difficult to move from the very basic tutorials to slightly more complicated uses that I need in a short time! thank you for your help.