# Watch for file changes and add changes to github?

Tags: macos, git

On OSX I want to create a script that 'when a file changes, automatically runs

```
git add [FILES CHANGED]; 
git commit -m "Changing ${file names}"; 
git push -u origin master"
```

I understand there is fswatch, however, this keeps a process running.

Maybe I can try running "git status" and if != "On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean" then automatically push to Github?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a command like "watch" or "inotifywait" on the Mac?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515730/is-there-a-command-like-watch-or-inotifywait-on-the-mac)

Comment: You need to use `fswatch` if you want to get something stable

Comment: @hek2mgl it's not a duplicate. There they asked if there exists a command, but I was hoping for an implementation using fswatch or the like.

Comment: Probably your question should state this more clearly. I retracted the close vote.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but I was also looking for an alternative solution and found rerun2. Perhaps it will also be useful to somebody else.

https://github.com/tartley/rerun2

From Tartley's readme:

> It runs COMMAND every time there's a filesystem modify event within
> your current directory (recursive). For example, it can re-run tests
> every time you hit 'save' in your editor. Or it can re-generate
> rendered output (html, SVG, etc) every time you save the source (e.g.
> Markdown or GraphViz dot).
>
> COMMAND needs to be a single parameter to rerun, hence if it contains
> spaces, either quote the whole thing:

```
rerun "ls ~"
```

or escape them:

```
rerun ls\ ~
```

**How to implement:**

If you take your code, and put it inside an update.sh script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
git add -u
git commit -m "Automatic update of modified files" && git push
```

Make it executable:

```
chmod u+x gitpush.sh
```

Create an alias to make things easier:

```
alias gitpush=/path/to/gitpush.sh:
```

Open the terminal, got to the directory you want to watch and run the command:

```
rerun gitpush
```

Now it will run gitpush everytime files changes in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to give up automatically responding to file modifications, you could just periodically run (e.g., via a crontab entry or something):

```
git add -u
git commit -m "Automatic update of modified files" && git push
```

The `git add -u` will stage any modified files, and "git commit" will only be successful if there are modifications to commit.

If you also want to pick up new files, you could use `git add -A` instead.

Comment: What if a file changes two times a minute?

Comment: There was no requirement stated in the question that said that they needed a separate commit for every individual change.

Comment: OP stated `[ a script which ] when a file changes, automatically runs` ... Suggesting `cron` is inappropriate here. `fswatch` needs to be used.

Comment: Yes, I read that too.  You and I are interpreting the question differently, and that's okay.

Comment: How can this get misinterpreted? Reacting on file changes is a common task in OS development and I doubt that kernel developers put so much effort on fs notification interfaces to finally end up users using cron.

Comment: I was hoping for a better solution than running a cron job. Similar to what @hek2mgl said I would ideally prefer a single commit for every file changed.