# fswatch to watch only a certain file extension

Tags: macos, watch, fswatch

I am using `fswatch` and only want it triggered if a file with extension `.xxx` is modified/created etc.  The documentation and the second reference below indicate that:

- All paths are accepted by default, unless an exclusion filter says otherwise.
- Inclusion filters may override any exclusion filter.
- The order in the definition of filters in the command line has no effect.

*Question:* What is the regular expression to use to *exclude* all files that do *not* match the `.xxx` extension?

### References:

- [Is there a command like "watch" or "inotifywait" on the Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515730/is-there-a-command-like-watch-or-inotifywait-on-the-mac)
- [Watch for a specific filetype](https://github.com/emcrisostomo/fswatch/issues/86)

### Platform:

- MacOS 10.9.5.

Comment: According to [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (stack overflow):
_a specific programming problem_, or
_software tools commonly used by programmers_ and
_a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development_.  Seems to me that this question meets those requirements.  I don't need the question opened, but seems odd to me that it was closed.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I'm `fswatch` author.  It may not be very intuitive, but `fswatch` includes *everything* unless an exclusion filter says otherwise.  Coming to your problem: you want to include all files with a given extension.  Rephrasing in term of exclusion and inclusion filters:

- You want to exclude *everything*.
- You want to include files with a given extension `ext`.

That is:

- To exclude *everything* you can add an exclusion filter matching any string: `.*`.
- To include files with a given extension `ext`, you add an inclusion filter matching any path ending with `.ext`: `\\.ext$`.  In this case you *need* to escape the dot `.` to match the literal dot, then the extension `ext` and then matching the *end* of the path with `$`.

The final command is:

```
$ fswatch [options] -e ".*" -i "\\.ext$"
```

If you want *case insensitive* filters (e.g. to match `eXt`, `Ext`, etc.), just add the `-I` option.

Comment: this isn't working for me on linux, I get no events at all. I could create a detailed issue on your github repo, but every issue since march has 0 replies.

Comment: @erandros I'm also experiencing similar issues (at first no output, soon after some output which is not reliable). Using a different monitor (`-m poll_monitor`) it seems to work fine.

Comment: I can't get this to work with Linux (Xubuntu 20.04) running in VirtualBox. Weird thing, I get "Invalid monitor name" when I specify `-m inotify`. Without filters everything works as expected

Comment: This is a timesaver. Thank you. I had guessed including only a single filetype involved excluding every other file type, but I wouldn't have known to double up on backslashes.

Comment: @erandros did you  found  the solution for linux?

Comment: @mozey did you  found  the solution for linux?

Comment: @DipeshKC I couldn't get the filters working how I wanted on Linux. So I wrote my own watcher that is a wrapper around golang fsnotity lib, see here https://github.com/mozey/watcher

Answer (score 5):

You may watch for changes to files of a single extension like this:

```
fswatch -e ".*" -i ".*/[^.]*\\.xxx$" .
```

This will exclude all files and then include all paths ending with `.xxx` (and also exclude files starting with a dot).

If you want to run a command on the file change, you may add the following:

```
fswatch -e ".*" -i ".*/[^.]*\\.xxx$" -0 . | xargs -0 -n 1 -I {} echo "File {} changed"
```

Comment: How would someone modify this to look for multiple file extensions?

Comment: You can just add the `-i` parameter multiple times, e.g., `fswatch -0 -o -e '.*' -i '.*/*\.xxx$' -i '.*/*\.yyy' . | xargs -0 -n1 -I{} bash -c 'echo {}'`