# How to mount a local directory to s3

Tags: amazon-s3, filesystems, aws-cli

Is there a way to keep a local folder mounted to s3 so that any time files are added to the folder, they are automatically added to s3 without needing human interaction?

I've seen

```
aws s3 sync ./mylocalfolder  s3://my-bucket
```

But this only runs once and exits.

Is there a way to keep the connection established?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a watch on the directory that you want to watch and trigger the sync that way.

There isn't an out of the box cli command that will keep s3 sync open.

`fswatch -o ~/path/to/watch | xargs -n1 -I{} ~/myAwsS3SyncScript.sh`

Here is a good post on [fswatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515730/is-there-a-command-like-watch-or-inotifywait-on-the-mac)

Comment: This works well.   Now I just have to translate it to work with inotifywait