# Continuously watch a socket file, run command when it doesn't exist?

Tags: shell, file, watch

It seems that when my screen is locked for some period of time, my `S.gpg-agent.ssh` disappears, and so in order to continue using my key I have to re-initialise it.

Obviously, this is a relatively frequent occurrence, so I've written a function for my shell to kill gpg-agent, restart it, and reset the appropriate environment variables.

---

This may be a bit of an 'X-Y problem', X being above this line, but I think Y below is more generally useful to know anyway.

---

How can I automatically run a command when an extant file no longer exists?

The best I've come up with is:

```
nohup echo "$file" | entr $command &
```

at login. But [entr](http://eradman.com/entrproject/entr.1.html) runs a command  when files change, not just deletion, so it's not clear to me how that will behave with a socket.

Comment: Why not use [`cron`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) daemon?

Comment: @Yasen because I'm not waiting for a time, I'm waiting for a file to disappear? And I don't want to poll it - I'll either be polling way too frequently, or I'll try to use it between polls and have to fix it manually anyway.

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, [`cron`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) daemon does not fit.

## Watch socket file deletion

Try `auditd`

```sh
# auditctl -w /var/run/<your_socket_file> -p wa 
$ tail -f /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep 'nametype=DELETE'
```

## Howto run a script if event occurred

If you want to run a script on socketile deletion, you can use `while` loop, e.g.:

```sh
tail -Fn0 /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep 'name=<your_socket_file>' | grep 'nametype=DELETE' \
while IFS= read -r line; do
  # your script here
done
```

*thx to [Tom Klino](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/30590/tom-klino) and his [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/350124/145897)*

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention the OS you're using, but if it's linux, you can use [`inotifywait`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/inotifywait.1.html) from the `inotify-tools` package:

```
#!/bin/sh

while inotifywait -qq -e delete_self /path/to/S.gpg-agent.ssh; do
    echo "Socket was deleted!"
    # Recreate it.
done
```

Comment: Thanks, I had dismissed it because I hoped for something cross-platform (Linux & macOS) but looking into it now seems `fswatch` is similar and available on both: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515730/is-there-a-command-like-watch-or-inotifywait-on-the-mac