# How to check for file changes on Mac OS using python

Tags: python, macos, directory, fsevents

I want to write a script that continuously checks a certain directory on a Mac OS for changing files. When I google for possible solutions I came upon MacFSEvents. However, when I try to pip install macfsevents I get the following error code:

```
Collecting macfsevents
Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/28/2e/1ff399cfd2a6a8ebb65152203c920643c2169aa507b2e96559d19baeb7c3/MacFSEvents-0.8.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: macfsevents
Running setup.py install for macfsevents ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
 command: 'c:\users\nllsme\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\nllsme\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-g5oqxirm\\macfsevents\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\nllsme\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-g5oqxirm\\macfsevents\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\nllsme\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_hqmm2_b\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile
     cwd: C:\Users\nllsme\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-g5oqxirm\macfsevents\
Complete output (14 lines):
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
copying fsevents.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
running build_ext
building '_fsevents' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8
creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\nllsme\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include -Ic:\users\nllsme\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.18362.0\winrt" /Tc_fsevents.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\_fsevents.obj
_fsevents.c
_fsevents.c(2): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\nllsme\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\nllsme\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-g5oqxirm\\macfsevents\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\nllsme\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-g5oqxirm\\macfsevents\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\nllsme\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_hqmm2_b\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile Check the logs for full command output.
```

Is there any way I can solve this installation issue or reach my goal using another API?

Comment: You're trying to install this on Windows.  The [MacFSEvents PyPI page](https://pypi.org/project/MacFSEvents/) lists Mac OS X 10.5+ (Leopard) as a requirement.

Comment: The missing file to compile is part of mac's xcode. You probably can't compile that module in Windows.

Comment: I'm confused, it looks like you're trying this on Windows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a command like "watch" or "inotifywait" on the Mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515730/is-there-a-command-like-watch-or-inotifywait-on-the-mac)