# Duplicate a created folder into another directory automatically

Tags: bash

I want to achieve the two following things:

1. Every time I create a new directory X in the directory Y the same directory X should be created in another directory Z automatically.
2. Every time the duplicated folder gets created in directory Z, in it a new .py document with the same name should be created. The first line of the .py document should also state the absolute path of directory X.

How would I go about that? I am on a mac. So I assume I would write some lines of code into my bash profile, so that every time I create a the new directory X in the directory Y with "mkdir" this chain of events gets triggered? Is that a good start?

Comment: you need fswatch, please check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1515730/is-there-a-command-like-watch-or-inotifywait-on-the-mac

Answer (score 0):

If you create a bash script, using commands but not limited to the following, `mkdir` `cp` `touch` `chmod` `chown` while checking the file permissions, and afterwards the group and user as well. You can then run the script instead of manually performing these actions.