# Portable Directory/File watch library in C / C++

Tags: c++, c, filesystems

Is there a portable library to watch for filesystem changes without polling?

I know there is

- [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) for Linux
- [solution for osx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442408/how-can-i-receive-notifications-of-filesystem-changes-in-os-x/1442426#1442426)
- [FindFirstChangeNotification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364417%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)for Windows
- [NIO.2](http://blogs.oracle.com/thejavatutorials/entry/watching_a_directory_for_changes) for Java
- [System.IO.FileSystemWatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx) for .NET

but i have not found any portable wrapper for those.

Is there a portable wrapper for Linux, Windows and OS X or a subset of those?

Comment: GLib's [GIO](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.29/GFileMonitor.html) uses GAMIN which covers Linux & FreeBSD, no idea about OSX or Windows.

Comment: Is Java not portable enough for you? Or do you explicitly need a C++ wrapper?

Comment: Java has a to big memory and diskspace footprint for the task

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[QFileSystemWatcher](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qfilesystemwatcher.html) -- Qt is very cross-platform.

Comment: Sounds like a possible solution. But I experienced the pre-build moc and slow compile/linking unsatisfactory. I still hope a leaner solution exists (without cutting it out of Qt by hand.)

Comment: CMake makes the MOC stuff very easy, QtCore is a very lightweight library, I never noticed significant extra time to compile/link but you might try GNU Gold as a faster replacement linker http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_(linker)

Comment: FYI: On Windows `QFileSystemWatcher` and `FindNextChangeNotification` wont work correctly on network shares on linx servers which use an outdated version of samba (we have a server running with version 3.0.22, which problems). In such cases you have to force QFileSystemWatcher to use the polling implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [jnotify](http://jnotify.sourceforge.net/). It's written in java and can run on all the major OSes.